# Erlang: What is most-wrong with this trie implementation?

Tags: erlang, trie

Over the holidays, my family loves to play Boggle. Problem is, I'm terrible at Boggle. So I did what any good programmer would do: wrote a program to play for me.

At the core of the algorithm is a simple [prefix trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), where each node is a `dict` of references to the next letters.

This is the `trie:add` implementation:

```
add([], Trie) ->
    dict:store(stop, true, Trie);

add([Ch|Rest], Trie) ->
    % setdefault(Key, Default, Dict) ->
    %     case dict:find(Key, Dict) of
    %         { ok, Val } -> { Dict, Val }
    %         error -> { dict:new(), Default }
    %     end.
    { NewTrie, SubTrie } = setdefault(Ch, dict:new(), Trie),
    NewSubTrie = add(Rest, SubTrie),
    dict:store(Ch, NewSubTrie, NewTrie).
```

And you can see the rest, along with an example of how it's used (at the bottom), here:

> http://gist.github.com/263513

Now, this being my first serious program in Erlang, I know there are probably a bunch of things wrong with it… But my immediate concern is that it uses **800 megabytes of RAM**.

So, what am I doing most-wrong? And how might I make it a bit less-wrong?

Comment: Ha.  I did that in PHP a few years ago.

Comment: How big is your input word list?

Comment: My word list is 200,000 words (or 2.5 megs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement this functionality by simply storing the words in an ets table:

```
% create table; add words
> ets:new(words, [named_table, set]).
> ets:insert(words, [{"zed"}]).  
> ets:insert(words, [{"zebra"}]).    

% check if word exists
> ets:lookup(words, "zed").          
[{"zed"}]

% check if "ze" has a continuation among the words
78> ets:match(words, {"ze" ++ '$1'}).
[["d"],["bra"]]
```

If trie is a must, but you can live with a non-functional approach, then you can try [digraph](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html)s, as Paul already suggested.

If you want to stay functional, you might save some bytes of memory by using structures using less memory, for example [proplist](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html)s, or records, such as `-record(node, {a,b,....,x,y,z})`.

Comment: Alright, so I've been tinkering with ets, but I've been getting issues with "bad argument". Maybe you know a simple solution? Question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964990/erlang-ets-reset-ets-table-after-getting-a-bad-argument

Comment: Alright, I've tinkered with the proplist implementation too... And it has hit an issue which causes the shell to hang. I've asked that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982257/erlang-erl-shell-hangs-after-building-a-large-data-structure (ps: thanks for all your help - it's much appreciated).

Answer (score 4):

I don't remember how much memory a dict takes, but let's estimate. You have 2.5e6 characters and 2e5 words. If your trie had no sharing at all, that would take 2.7e6 associations in the dicts (one for each character and each 'stop' symbol). A simple purely-functional dict representation would maybe 4 words per association -- it could be less, but I'm trying to get an upper bound. On a 64-bit machine, that'd take 8*4*2.7 million bytes, or 86 megabytes. That's only a tenth of your 800M, so something's surely wrong here.

**Update:** [dict.erl](http://web.mit.edu/erlang_vR11B-5/arch/sun4x_510/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-1.14.5/src/dict.erl) represents dicts with a hashtable; this implies lots of overhead when you have a lot of very small dicts, as you do. I'd try changing your code to use the [proplists](http://web.mit.edu/erlang_vR11B-5/arch/sun4x_510/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-1.14.5/src/proplists.erl) module, which ought to match my calculations above.

Comment: To check how much memory a dict() construct takes, call: `erts_debug:flat_size(dict:new())`. It returns 46 words, which is 184 bytes on a 32-bit system, or 368 bytes on a 64-bit one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... Although I've run into a strange problem where the shell hangs when I create my proplist-based-trie, which I've asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982257/erlang-erl-shell-hangs-after-building-a-large-data-structure - could you, by any chance, offer any insight there?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to solve the problem is going through the word list and see if the word can be constructed from the dice. That way you need very little RAM, and it might be more fun to code. (optimizing and concurrency)

Answer (score 2):

Look into [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph)s.  They're much more compact than tries.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your algorithm, but if you're storing that much data, maybe you should look into using Erlang's built-in digraph library to represent your trie, instead of so many dicts.
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html

Answer (score 1):

If all words are in English, and the case doesn't matter, all characters can be encoded by numbers from 1 to 26 (and in fact, in Erlang they *are* numbers from 97 to 122), reserving 0 for stop. So you can use the [`array` module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/array.html) as well.